# How to create objects dynamically?

Tags: c++, dynamicobject

I am new to coding, I'm trying to learn C++. I am making a roulette game, and I am trying to use classes and objects. I have a class called Bets, that stores the players bet choice in an object, it could be a number, or an outside bet like odd or even. This works fine, but I would like to give the user the option to place multiple bets in the same spin, so when the user answers yes to the question, "Place another bet?", I would like another object to be made. Could someone please help me create multiple objects of the same class?

Comment: Read any good C++ tutorial. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: No, read a good C++ _book_.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for mentoring/supervision/tutorialling. SO is not a helpdesk or a chat room or a message board or a forum. You should purchase a C++ book and, optionally, recruit a friend or teacher to step you through it. Far too broad for a Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword **new** lets you create a new object. C++ is a little different than a language like .Net or Java, if you are familiar with those languages. The C++ languages uses the keyword **new**, but **new** return a "pointer" to the new object. If your class is named "Bet", then the statement:

```
Bet *betPointer = new Bet();
```

Will create a new "Bet" object and assign its pointer to the variable "betPointer".

If bet has a property names "color" that return a string, then instead of writing:

```
betPointer.color //this is wrong

betPointer->color //this is correct.
```

My favorite site to research these kinds of questions is http://www.cplusplus.com. Follow this link for a more information and examples using the keyword **new**:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%2k0new/